# Show newlines in html textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea and I set its text to a string with `\n` in it. I would expect that to represent a line break.

```
$("#ConfirmEmailText").text("test\n\ntest\ntest");
```

However, I just get what looks like a tab rather than a new line.

If I add some additional text to the box, and press enter. I can see the text on seperate line. I then take the text in this box and send it in an email. In the email both the `\n` and my [enter]s from when I added some text show up as newlines in the email...

Why does this not display correctly in my textarea?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show separation between newlines in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408950/show-separation-between-newlines-in-textarea)

Comment: @Diodeus: I don't think so, that question is about adding a paragraph marker at the hard break. I think the OP here just wants the hard breaks to be respected.

Comment: @T.J. thats correct, when my string has a `\n` in it I want it to show up that same as if the user pressed `enter` within the the text area.

Comment: @people voting for close - It would be nice if you commented and said why you were going to vote to close and gave me a chance to respond... It's not a duplicate so i'm not sure why this would need to be closed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `value` not the `innerText`;

```
$("#ConfirmEmailText").val("test\n\ntest\ntest");
```

Comment: This works, but using a variable instead of the text doesn't seem to work. I verified the value with an alert.

Comment: @Yster — Should work fine with a variable. You might want to [create a proper test case](http://sscce.org/) and then [ask a new question](/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
   text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n');
```

Or use the DOM structure's .nodeValue property.

**EDIT :** i may have not been clear. Instead of using innerHTML to set the text try using nodeValue

Answer (score 0):

try

```
text = text.replace("\n","<br/>");
```