# Line breaks won't display in textarea in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

Using jQuery's `.load()` method I'm loading text into a textarea. Works fine in Chrome & FF. As always, IE just has to be different and won't display the line breaks.

I've tried `white-space:pre-wrap` with no luck.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
$('#textarea').load('data.php');
```

The **data.php** simply queries a MySql database and prints the results.

Comment: What constitutes the line breaks? Are they \r\n?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're compatibility problems with IE when using `innerHTML()`. As Jquery's `.html()` and `.load()` methods both use `innerHTML()`, they by extension can result in some issues.
One solution is to use `.text()` instead. If you want to load text into a `<textarea>` using AJAX and Jquery you need to do something like this:

```
$('#textarea').post('data.php',function(data){
        $(this).text(data);
    })
);
```

Comment: This did not work for me, but I was able to solve my problem by using `.val` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583040/show-newlines-in-html-textarea/5583094#5583094

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a [line-ending issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems). Are the line breaks in the text `\n`s or `\r\n`s? If they're just `\n`s try normalizing the text. You can do this with a bit of JavaScript:

```
function normalizeNewlines(text)
{
    return text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\r\n');
}
```

This is a solution that's worked for me in the past when doing essentially the reverse: I needed to take text out of a `<pre>` that could be pasted into <sup><sub>`!@#$ing`</sub></sup> Notepad and show up with the line breaks intact.

Comment: Nice to see that one Matt proposes a cause and another Matt writes a solution to that cause at the same time. ;)

Comment: We Matts have a special bond :)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your reply. I've tried this with no luck. I've tried to check for special characters in the string using `data.indexOf('\\')` is this right?

Comment: @Gary, try `data.indexOf('\n')`, the character is not literally a slash then a letter, it's a single character, it's just visually displayed in code that way.

Comment: @Matt Greer Thanks, I thought I tried that, but obviously I miss-typed, because that works. Pheww.

Answer (score 1):

I used kendoui grid in inline edit mode, for description field textare were applyed, the solution were for ie the inline style:

```
<textarea style="white-space:pre-wrap;" name="' + options.field + '" ...
```

And the following code in keydown event:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```