# Internet Explorer \n line breaks not working

Tags: javascript

In all versions of IE (I'm testing IE11 at the moment) new line breaks inside of `textarea` elements aren't working...

```
function id_(id)
{ 
 var r = false;
 if (document.getElementById(id))
 {
  r = document.getElementById(id);
 }
 return r;
}

window.onload = function()
{
 for (i in document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0])
 {
  id_('test').value = id_('test').value + '\n' +i;
 }
}
```

How can I force IE to break lines in a `textarea` element? No frameworks.

I've tried `\n\r`, `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ff5kqtru/ this seems to work in IE11. What are u trying to achieve by that loop?

Comment: Try this `$('#test').val($('#test').value + '\n' +i);` ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583040/show-newlines-in-html-textarea/5583094#5583094

Comment: `for (i in document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0])` seems weird, are you sure it isn't `for (i in document.getElementsByTagName('audio'))`?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić, I assume he's iterating through the properties of the first `audio` tag, hence the `[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After minimizing the code the issue was the CSS `white-space` property which I fixed with the code below.

```
* {white-space: nowrap;}
textarea {white-space: pre;}
```

Comment: It's really strange that IE ignores line feeds when white-space is set to `nowrap`.  I've tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera, and only IE shows this behavior.  According to http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space, line breaks *should* be suppressed for `nowrap`, so is it possible that IE is the *only* browser to get this right?

Comment: Even though we all hate IE I have to admit when they DO make an effort to interpret things correctly they really do well at doing so. Case in point when they took on `border-radius` (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/19/the-css-corner-about-css-corners.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much. Safari has just started doing this, so I was very grateful to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

In IE, `\n` does indeed generate line breaks in `textarea` elements. That is, this code:

```
<textarea id="target">default text here</textarea>
<script>document.getElementById('target').value = 'a\nb';</script>
```

does, in IE, result in a textarea which holds the value `default text here` for an unimaginably short time followed by the value:

```
a
b
```

If you really want to test your browser, I have put this on a JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/91mj2arh/

Answer (score 1):

This Fiddle based on your code adds line feeds in my version of IE11, and it seems to accomplish what you're looking for to iterate the `audio` element's properties:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ff5kqtru/5/**

If you post your HTML, we may be able to spot a problem.